# Rocket chat upgrade Error: Can't find migration version XXX

Tags: mongodb, upgrade, rocket.chat

I'm using old Rocketchat version 3.2.1 instance with external mongodb version 4.2.23
My desire is to upgrade it by using newer version insatnce, tried connecting new rocketchat version 5.3.1 instance to the external mongodb, result rocketchat service failing on "Error: Can't find migration version 123
Any advice what am I missing or how to achieve it?

Database Migration 123 is the current on old, working instance.

Connecting external mongodb 4.2.23 from old rocketchat version instance 3.2.1 to newer rocketchat version 5.3.0 instance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the step from 3.2.1 to 5.3.1 is too big. Every release has an internal version number (migration version). The database must have the same version (schema and content constraints). If you install a new release, it will bring a list of migration steps, to migrate your database from 123 to whatever the new release is. If the version gap is too big, this list might not be complete anymore (it doesn't go back enough). In this case, you need to install another version first (in this case 4.x) which will do half of the migration. After this, you are ready to go to 5.3.1 (and then even 6.x)

Unfortunately, I can't find documentation, which versions you will need, or which version goes back enough.